# php file upload different types of files

Tags: php, file-upload

I'm trying to upload files in php using the following function :

```
public function fileUpload($FILES){
    $num_of_uploads = 1;
    $max_file_size = 1048576; //can't be larger than 1 MB

    $T = array ();
    foreach($_FILES["file"]["error"] as $key=>$value){

        if($_FILES["file"]["name"][$key] != ""){

            if($value == UPLOAD_ERR_OK){

                $v = array ();

                $origfilename = $_FILES["file"]["name"][$key];
                $filename = explode(".", $_FILES["file"]["name"][$key]);
                $filenameext = $filename[count($filename) - 1];

                $v['name'] = $filename[0];
                $v['extension'] = $filename[1];
                $v['type'] = $_FILES["file"]["type"][$key];

                unset($filename[count($filename) - 1]);
                $filename = implode(".", $filename);
                $filename = "file__" . time() . "." . $filenameext;

                if($_FILES["file"]["size"][$key] < $max_file_size){
                    $v['content'] = file_get_contents($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"][$key]);
                    $T[] = $v;
                }else{
                    throw new Exception($origfilename . " file size inaccepted!<br />");
                }

            }else{
                throw new Exception($origfilename . " Error of upload <br />");
            }
        }
    }
    return $T;
}
```

This function works great with txt types, but when I'm testing pdf, or gif or jpg, it returns a damaged file.

Comment: check you php.ini file for max file upload size and max post size.  Ensure upload size is not greater than that

Comment: I have no probleme with file size, i'm testting with 70Ko file and it's not working

Comment: What error you are getting?

Comment: I have no error, but when I'm downloading it, the document is damaged

Comment: Try to access uploaded file directly from uploaded location. There is a chance that during file download you might not have set headers properly. And due to that document is not downloading/open properly.

Comment: It's stored in the tmp folder. PHP will automatically delete it when the script ends.

Comment: Yes, I know that. I want to say is after moving file to destination path using move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"][$key], $dest_path), check the file on destination location

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I know, `file_get_contents()` works well on `text/html` types.
However, for other file types you should parse their text content first to use it in further processing. Try opening any `.pdf` in Notepad to see it's text content.

For uploading purposes, use `move_uploaded_file()` in your cycle, like this:

```
move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"][$key], $filename);
```

Of course, without trying to get text content from uploaded file.

Comment: move_uploaded_file function must have in second parameter the file destination, not the filename,  
**move_uploaded_file($_FILES['Filedata']['tmp_name'], $file_src);**
Here I'm not saving files in a specific destination

Comment: Sure, but filename will work as destination for current working directory as well. If for some reason you want to use file content for direct download, you'll need to properly set `Content-type` headers then, depending on the current file extension.

Answer (score 1):

For downloading the file, you need to set headers. So, at the starting of function try setting any of below header for png or jpeg files:

```
//For png file
header("Content-Type: image/png");
//For jpeg file
header("Content-Type: image/jpeg");
```